# Trying to generate a list containing multiple variables from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
<?php
function itemList(){
    $items= array(
        "skateboard" => array(
            "name" => "Skateboard"
            "type" => "drawings"
            "namestripped" => "skateboard"
        ),
        "looklocal" => array(
            "name" => "Look Local"
            "type" => "graphic-design"
            "namestripped" => "looklocal"
        ),
    );          
    reset($items);          
    while (list(, $value) = each($items)) {
        echo '<li class="item '. $value["type"] .'">';
        echo '<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/portfolio/' . $value["type"] . '/'. $value["namestripped"] . '_l.jpg">';
        echo '<img src="images/portfolio/' . $value["type"] . '/'. $value["namestripped"] . '.jpg" alt="' . $value . '"/>';   
        echo '<h3>' . $value["name"] . '</h3>';                                                   echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
?>
```

How badly have I messed up the syntax? When I try this code it doesn't output anything, not even the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only defines the function, but doesn't execute it.

You would execute it like so:

```
itemList();
```

**EDIT** You also had some typo's in your PHP code. Here is the fixed version:

```
function itemList()
{
    $items = array(
        "skateboard" => array(
            "name"         => "Skateboard",
            "type"         => "drawings",
            "namestripped" => "skateboard"
        ),
        "looklocal" => array(
            "name"         => "Look Local",
            "type"         => "graphic-design",
            "namestripped" => "looklocal"
        ),
    );          

    foreach ($items AS $item)
    {
        echo '<li class="item '. $item["type"] .'">';
        echo '<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/portfolio/' . $item["type"] . '/'. $item["namestripped"] . '_l.jpg">';
        echo '<img src="images/portfolio/' . $item["type"] . '/'. $item["namestripped"] . '.jpg" alt="' . $item . '"/>';   
        echo '<h3>' . $item["name"] . '</h3>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
}

itemList();
```

Comment: I have done that and I got it working with a single dimensional array. I tried to edit it for a multi dimensional array and it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

you have some syntax errors.

```
$items= array(
                "skateboard" => array(
                                        "name" => "Skateboard"
                                        "type" => "drawings"
                                        "namestripped" => "skateboard"
                                        ),
                "looklocal" => array(
                                        "name" => "Look Local"
                                        "type" => "graphic-design"
                                        "namestripped" => "looklocal"
                                        ),
                );;
```

should be:

```
$items= array(
                "skateboard" => array(
                                        "name" => "Skateboard",
                                        "type" => "drawings",
                                        "namestripped" => "skateboard"
                                        ),
                "looklocal" => array(
                                        "name" => "Look Local",
                                        "type" => "graphic-design",
                                        "namestripped" => "looklocal"
                                        )
                );
```

And you need to call the itemList() function somewhere else.

besides that, i don't know what should be the output.